# How expensive can a contract factory be?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

I have a `Bakery.sol` and `Cookies.sol` contract. Bakery has a function `bakeCookie()`. Since creation of contracts cost some ETH, how costly will it be to have new `Cookie` contracts being created very frequently? Is there a way to reduce the cost?

Comment: explain in detail, if its possible some eg

Comment: Check out clone factory https://github.com/yarrumretep/clone-factory

Comment: You should check if ``struct`` is a better choice for your requirement. It will be cheaper than deploying a contract.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [clone-factory](http://github.com/yarrumretep/clone-factory) module, your Bakery contract could inherit from CloneFactory and then bakeCookies() could clone a master Cookie.sol contract that gets deployed once.  bakeCookies() would then initialize the new clone contract with whatever initialization data is necessary for that specific Cookie.

Check out the ThingFactory and Thing contracts at https://github.com/yarrumretep/clone-factory/tree/master/test